# Indexing list elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was looking at [@evansb](https://github.com/evansb)'s solution to a homework problem in [CIS 194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194). Basically, the problem asks to double every other element in a list and Evan's solution is this:

```
-- Exercise 3 -----------------------------------------

-- Double every second number in a list starting on the left.
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther = zipWith
  (\x y -> if x `mod` 2 == 0 then y * 2 else y) [(1::Integer)..]
```

I am kind of confused about `(1::Integer)`, does `1`reference the first index? So in the lambda function `x` corresponds to the index and `y` corresponds to the actual element at that index?

Comment: FYI, `zipWith ($) (cycle [(2*), id])` works too and is probably more efficient (no need to compute `mod`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[(1::Integer)..]` is the list of all integers, starting from 1. The `::Integer` specifies the type.

For the rest of your question: The elements from `[(1::Integer)..]` will become the values of `x`. The list that the function `doubleEveryOther` will be called with will provide the values for `y`. So the first list is basically just used as a 1-based index.

Comment: Thanks. Does the type (Integer) have to be specified?

Comment: @user245954 No, it does not. The `mod` function helps the compiler with inferring the type here: `mod :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a`. In other words, it doesn't matter what kind of type you put there, as long as it is integral, but this constraint is already enforces by the function passed by `zipWith`.

Comment: @Undreren I disagree. The type of `mod` does not unambiguously define the type of `1`, so without an annotation GHC has to apply a default which might be different from `Integer`.

Comment: @chi It might, but it won't matter. It runs fine in GHCi without it. I tested it before writing the comment.